# Docker Compose - bind source path does not exist

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my docker compose service I have the following:

```
volumes:
      - ~/DockerStuff/Projects:/root/Documents/Projects
      - ~/DockerStuff/Downloads:/root/Downloads
```

But when I run `docker compose` up I'm being told:
`Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist`

I keep seeing things saying that you can create bind volumes and if the host directory doesn't exist, Docker shall create it on the fly.  But these seem specific to DockerFile setups rather than compose files.

Is such functionality possible in docker compose too? :)

Comment: `~`  expansion is a feature implemented by Unix shells. If you want it anywhere else, it needs to be implemented as well. Apparently [Docker Compose hasn't done it](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6506).

Comment: Wish it were this simple :( Unfortunately ${HOME} produces the same error.  But thank you for pointing this out, would have been poor show to publish this if it didn't work on Windows!

Answer (score 6):

In order to create the host folder for the docker-compose volume binding if it doesn't exist just add `bind.create_host_path` to your volumes section  -

```
volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: localFolder/subFolderIfNeeded
        target: /data
        bind:
          create_host_path: true
```

NOTE: Tested on Docker compose 2.15.1

Answer (score 2):

The `~` symbols is not expanded by docker compose.

You have to rely on this approach:

**building script**

```
HOME=${HOME} docker-compose ... command options ...
```

**docker compose yaml**

```yaml
volumes:
      - ${HOME}/DockerStuff/Projects:/root/Documents/Projects
      - ${HOME}/DockerStuff/Downloads:/root/Downloads
```

Comment: This `~` symbol did seem to be getting expanded for me (perhaps a mac specific thing.  I've tried changing to your suggestion to be careful though, but I'm getting the same error message :( and the error is followed up by the full path I'm aiming for, which is correct.

Comment: @apbarratt i faced the same situation, I could only resolve it by moving my project directory back to where it was originally... so the issue was caused by changing that path. Would love to understand this better so that I could move things around if I wish! let me know how you did with this, thanks!